# What had Esther done in "The Bell Jar" by Sylvia Plath?

Tags: sylvia-plath, the-bell-jar

In *The Bell Jar* by Sylvia Plath, Esther mentions that she drank some water with cherry blossoms in Mrs Guinea’s house and says that “it was only much later, […], that [she] learned what [she] had done”.

What exactly was it that she had done?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The water with cherry blossoms was a fingerbowl, intended for a diner to wash their fingers. Drinking the water (and eating the blossoms!) is a social faux pas, as Esther realized subsequently.